# parameter "created_on" not found in the collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I am passing three parameters to a stored procedure,no problem with the two parameters but only one parameter is not being identified. Here's the code:

```
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("AppTableDetails", connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tname",tablename);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@created_on",definedon);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@createdBy", createdby);
        connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        connection.Close();
```

The stored procedure is:

```
    ALTER DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `AppTableDetails`( IN tname varchar(40),

IN created_on datetime,
IN createdBy varchar(40))
BEGIN
insert into `app_tables` (tablename,tableid,defined_on,appid,created_by)
values ( tname,0,created_on,(select max(appid) from application), createdBy);
END
```

When i debug the file, i get an error: parameter "created_on" not found in the collection. But i have clearly written the stored procedure. What's the problem? help.

Comment: what are the types of `definedon` & `createdby`?

Comment: did u execute the same procedure from mysql?

Comment: @Damith- defiendon and createdby both are of string type.

Comment: @RajasekarGunasekaran- I am calling the procedure in my c# code. I didn't execute in mysql. Do i have to?

Comment: @RajasekarGunasekaran- I am able to execute it from mysql workbench.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `IN created_on datetime`, to `IN created_on varchar(40),`

or

Change `IN created_on datetime`, to `IN created_on DATETIME = NULL,`

Comment: @RameshRams- i tried with `IN created_on varchar(40)` this, but still getting the same error. `IN created_on DATETIME = NULL,` is giving syntax error.

Comment: It is working! i changed the type of `created_on` to `varchar(40)`, also the `created_on` column in the database table (which was of type `datetime`) to `varchar(40)`. Thanks!